# ng-click show data in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, codeigniter

I want to show data using `ng-click`

First i have listing for of all the companies, this works fine. it displays all the companies.:

```
<div class="col-xs-3" ng-repeat="item in companyData"> 
   <a ng-click="getPackageInfo({id:item.iCompanyID})" class="block panel padder-v bg-primary item">
   <span class="text-white block">{{item.vCompanyName}}</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

Now on click of company name, i have to display other info like packges of that company, for that i have done this under above `div`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in pData" class="col-xs-3">
        <a ng-click="" class="block panel padder-v bg-primary item">
               <span class="text-white block">{{item.vPackageName}}</span>
        </a>
</div>
```

In `controller.js` i did this, **getPackageInDetail** will return package listing according to company id:

```
    function getPackageInfo(id) {
        SubscriptionoptioncompanylistFactory.getPackageInDetail(id).
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.pData = data;
        }).
        error(function(data,status,header,config) {
            $scope.pData = 0;
        });
};
```

How can i append the data according to company clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.push.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Merging_two_arrays) can be used for merging two arrays.

> Merge the second array into the first one

```
//Define an empty array 
$scope.pData = [];

$scope.getPackageInfo = function(id) {
    SubscriptionoptioncompanylistFactory.getPackageInDetail(id).
    success(function(data) {
        Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.pData, data); //Merge the array
    });
};
```

Additionally, I think you need to pass ID properly

```
<a ng-click="getPackageInfo(item.iCompanyID)">
```

Comment: `getPackageInfo(item.iCompanyID)` this is not printing id

Comment: @hnn, You don't need to print it, You should define the function `getPackageInfo` in `$scope` object

Comment: but at first `iCompanyID` is not going to pass in here: **<a ng-click="getPackageInfo(item.iCompanyID)">**

Comment: it is displaying this: `ng-click="getPackageInfo({id:item.iCompanyID})"`

Comment: @hnn, It will pass when you click on the link, just do an alert and if its working as above the go with that

Comment: but 1 question, how can i clear the dive before getting clicked on another company.?

Comment: @hnn, if you are refereeing to package div them simply use `$scope.pData= data;`

Comment: i did it.. but if pData is an empty then i want to display message. how can i do?

Comment: I did this if **pData** is not an empty:  `<div ng-if="pData.length > 0" ng-repeat="item in pData" class="packages-data">
                            <a ng-click="getPackageInfo({{item.iPackageId}})" class="col-xs-3">
                                <span class="block">{{item.vPackageName}}</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>`

Comment: now if pData is empty then display msg. how can i do?

Comment: @hnn, Create a separate DIV like `div ng-if="pData.length == 0">Some message</div>`

Comment: not working.. it's displaying on page load and also not displaying any message when there is no data..